# Why 'longtable' doesn't work?

Tags: tables, longtable

I have a long table that I would like to span as many pages as necessary. I used `longtable` within `landscape` but it gives me an error. This is my code:

```
\begin{document}


\begin{landscape}

\begin{longtable}[H]

\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{c}r}
    \hline 
    Description   & T & Source & Geography & Start & End & F \\ 
    \hline 

     \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Real Activity}} \\ 

    Retail sales volume index & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 10 &  Y \\
    Manufacturing turnover index  & 6 & 3 & 0 & 3 &  8 &  Y \\
    Construction production index       & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  7 & Y  \\
    Retail sales of non-food production (excl. fuel)  & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 & Y  \\
    Industrial Production (excluding construction)  & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 &  Y \\
    Industrial Production: manufacturing  & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 & Y  \\
     Industrial Production: energy  & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 &   \\
     Industrial Production: consumer goods & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 &  Y \\
     Industrial Production: consumer durables & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 &  Y \\
     Industrial Production: capital goods & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 &  Y \\
     Industrial Production: consumer non-durables & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 & Y  \\
     Industrial Production: intermediate goods & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 &  Y \\
     New orders: manufacturing & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 &  Y \\
     New orders: capital goods & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 &  Y \\
     New orders: consumer durables & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 & Y  \\
     New orders: consumer non-durables  & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 &  Y \\
     New orders: intermediate goods  & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 & Y  \\

    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Prices}} \\ 

    Harmonised Index of COnsumer Prices (HICP) & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 10 &  Y \\
    HICP: energy    & 6 & 3 & 0 & 3 &  8 &  Y \\
    HICP: food    & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  7 &  Y \\
    HICP: goods    & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 &  Y \\
    HICP: excl. energy    & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 &  Y \\
    Producer Price Index (PPI)    & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 &  Y \\
    Oil Prices (Brent)    & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 &  Y \\

    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Surveys}} \\ 

    Economic Sentiment Indicator (ESI): industrial confidence & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 10 &  Y \\
    ESI: consumer confidence  & 6 & 3 & 0 & 3 &  8 &  Y \\
    ESI: economic sentiment & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  7 &  Y \\
    ESI: business climate & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 &  Y \\


\end{tabular}

\end{longtable}


\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: the syntax you show is unlike any example in the longtable manual. longtable does not have an H argument and you are missing the `{cccc}` column specification argument, and  your longtable  is just a single row single column with a `tabular` in the cell so no page breaking is possible.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How can I fix it to make it work on for page breaking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please see the longtable documentation, you want something like

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable,pdflscape}

\begin{document}



\begin{landscape}

\begin{longtable}{l*{6}{c}r}
    \hline 
    Description   & T & Source & Geography & Start & End & F \\ 
    \hline 
\endhead
     \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Real Activity}} \\ 

    Retail sales volume index & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 10 &  Y \\
    Manufacturing turnover index  & 6 & 3 & 0 & 3 &  8 &  Y \\
    Construction production index       & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  7 & Y  \\
    Retail sales of non-food production (excl. fuel)  & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 & Y  \\
    Industrial Production (excluding construction)  & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 &  Y \\
    Industrial Production: manufacturing  & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 & Y  \\
     Industrial Production: energy  & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 &   \\
     Industrial Production: consumer goods & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 &  Y \\
     Industrial Production: consumer durables & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 &  Y \\
     Industrial Production: capital goods & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 &  Y \\
     Industrial Production: consumer non-durables & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 & Y  \\
     Industrial Production: intermediate goods & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 &  Y \\
     New orders: manufacturing & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 &  Y \\
     New orders: capital goods & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 &  Y \\
     New orders: consumer durables & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 & Y  \\
     New orders: consumer non-durables  & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 &  Y \\
     New orders: intermediate goods  & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 & Y  \\

    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Prices}} \\ 

    Harmonised Index of COnsumer Prices (HICP) & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 10 &  Y \\
    HICP: energy    & 6 & 3 & 0 & 3 &  8 &  Y \\
    HICP: food    & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  7 &  Y \\
    HICP: goods    & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 &  Y \\
    HICP: excl. energy    & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 &  Y \\
    Producer Price Index (PPI)    & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 &  Y \\
    Oil Prices (Brent)    & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 &  Y \\

    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Surveys}} \\ 

    Economic Sentiment Indicator (ESI): industrial confidence & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 10 &  Y \\
    ESI: consumer confidence  & 6 & 3 & 0 & 3 &  8 &  Y \\
    ESI: economic sentiment & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  7 &  Y \\
    ESI: business climate & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 &  Y \\



\end{longtable}


\end{landscape}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Very helpful, thanks so much!